# .NET 5 WinForms FolderBrowserDialog shows file dialogue that can select only folders

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, .net-5

I expected something like the first image below, but when run the following code,

```
        var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.Description = " test";
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        if(fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
```

I get the second image below. Why is that? Is .NET changed? Can I get the dialogue like the first one?

[image]
[image]

Comment: `fbd.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=net-5.0

Comment: @HansPassant That worked, but this is strange. MSDN documentation says it is something about Windows Vista, but I think I have gotten the folder browser dialogue without this value set to false even after Windows 10 was released. Why suddenly do they work differently now?

Comment: Because you target .NETCore and run on Win10.  This dialog is built into the OS, not .NET, and normally what the user sees when other programs prompt for a folder.  .NETCore 3.0 was a great opportunity to modernize Winforms.  Same thing happened at .NETFramework 3.5 for OpenFileDialog and friends, enabling the native Vista dialogs.  Trying to turn the clock back to familiar time is not a great idea.

Comment: @HansPassant The old FBD is not perfect and has lots of points that can be improved, but the new one (modified FileOpenDialog) seems worse. I mean, I cannot see the directory hierarchy structure.

Comment: Well, you can, left panel.  Users are not normally that adventurous, the recently used entries there are quite useful.  It's your program, do what you want.